# Where to "set DISABLE_MANUAL_TARGET_ORDER_BUILD_WARNING"

Tags: xcode, xcode13

We have a complex Xcode workspace with loads of dependencies and dependencies of dependencies. The order of building them matters and Xcode <13 never was able to figure out the correct order using the "Parallelize Build" setting of the Xcode scheme(s), thus this option was unticket for us.

Now with Xcode 13, the schemes options have changes to "Dependency Order" and "Manual Order". We are using the later due to the above mentioned reasons.

Building this, Xcode gives us this warning:

> Building targets in manual order is deprecated - choose Dependency Order in scheme settings instead, or set DISABLE_MANUAL_TARGET_ORDER_BUILD_WARNING in any of the targets in the current scheme to suppress this warning.

but we can not find where to set this.

Question: Where in Xcode do we have to set DISABLE_MANUAL_TARGET_ORDER_BUILD_WARNING to suppress this warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's done on the Build Settings tab for the target that the scheme is supposed to build. Click the + button and choose Add User-Defined Setting. The name is `DISABLE_MANUAL_TARGET_ORDER_BUILD_WARNING` and the value I believe can be anything, but I can confirm that if I set it to `YES` it works to suppress the warning.

Comment: The value does matter. Setting it to TRUE, YES, true, 1, etc. suppresses the warning, setting it to FALSE, NO, false, 0, etc. explicitly enables the warning (so with such a value it would even stay enabled if a future version of Xcode would change the default value of that setting to disabled).

Comment: did not help me resolve the issue, the error still shows